# Direct image of coherent analytic sheaves

Tags: algebraic-geometry, sheaf-theory, coherent-sheaves

Given holomorphic varieties $X$ and $Y$, and let $\phi: X \rightarrow Y$ be a morphism between these varieties. Consider a coherent analytic sheaf $\mathcal{S}$ on $X.$ Why, in general the direct image $\phi_{*} \mathcal{S}$ is not a coherent analytic sheaf on $Y$? Could someone give to me a counterexample?

Comment: If $\phi$ is flat, ${\phi_*(S)}_y = H^0(\phi^{-1}(y), S)$ by base change, this shows that if the fiber has "too many global sections" (typically is not compact) then $\phi_* \mathcal S$ is not coherent, this is why you need $\phi$ proper to ensure that the (higher) direct images are coherent.

Answer (score 4):

For a very simple example, let $X=\mathbb{C}$, let $Y$ be a point, and let $\mathcal{S}=\mathcal{O}_X$.  Then $\phi_*\mathcal{S}(Y)=\mathcal{O}_X(X)$ is the space of all holomorphic functions on $X$.  Since this is infinite-dimensional over $\mathcal{O}_Y(Y)=\mathbb{C}$, the sheaf $\phi_*\mathcal{S}$ cannot be coherent.